# Blurring content layered behind a card using Jetpack Compose on Android

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-jetpack-compose, android-blur-effect

I am trying to achieve the blur effect like highlighted in [this post](https://twitter.com/TAEvangelist/status/1486008917830385673):

[image]

I'm using Jetpack Compose:

```
@Composable
fun MainApp() {
    val linearGradientBrush = Brush.linearGradient(
        colors = listOf(
            Color(0xFF5995EE),
            Color(0xFFB226E1),
            Color(0xFFE28548)
        ),
        start = Offset(Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY, 0f),
        end = Offset(0f, Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY),
    )

    val transparentGradientBrush = Brush.linearGradient(
        colors = listOf(
            Color(0x66FFFFFF),
            Color(0x1AFFFFFF)
        )
    )
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Box() {
            Card(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(150.dp)
//                    .blur(10.dp, edgeTreatment = BlurredEdgeTreatment.Unbounded)
                    .clip(shape = CircleShape)

                    .background(linearGradientBrush),

                backgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
                elevation = 0.dp,
            ) {
            }

            Card(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(150.dp)
                    .offset(x = -75.dp, y = 40.dp)
                    .blur(5.dp, edgeTreatment = BlurredEdgeTreatment.Unbounded)
                    .clip(RoundedCornerShape(30.dp))
                    .background(transparentGradientBrush),
                backgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
                elevation = 0.dp
            ) {

            }
        }

    }
}
```

However, the output I get is this:

[image]

How do I achieve the effect from the tweet above the layer in front also blurs the layer behind? Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: I've been exploring the [BlurView](https://github.com/Dimezis/BlurView) library written for Android Views. I think this library will help me get the desired effect but I am unable to figure out how to use this library with Jetpack Compose either.

Comment: did you get this to work?

Comment: The problem with Modifier.blur is it only apply blurs to its content and doesn't effectively show blur on content behind, probably look at this: https://betterprogramming.pub/glassmorphism-in-jetpack-compose-for-scrolling-item-b0c5824b55d0

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/x3rocode/xblur-compose/tree/main

I made simple realtime compose blur! 
try this.

[image: xblur]

Comment: This doesn't work -> Failed to resolve: com.github.x3rocode:xblur-compose:1.0.1

Comment: Nice but about a generic background blur? Like apply background blur to a Card?

Comment: it works on android 13 and onwards only.